# Echo array values of column not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to display the values of my array. but instead of displaying:

> ***1509 1510 1511*** it display ***ArrayArrayArray***. What does it mean?

```
include("db_PSIS.php");
$sql_dc = "SELECT Child, Datecode 
                    FROM traveller_merging15
                    WHERE Parent='" . $_REQUEST["txt_traveller_no"] . "'
                    ORDER BY Merge_ID ASC";
$res_dc = mysql_query($sql_dc);

$dcode1 = $row_dc['Datecode'];
$storeArray = array();

if (!$res_dc) {
    echo "No data fetched!";
} else {
    while ($row_dc = mysql_fetch_array($res_dc, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $storeArray[] = $dcode1;
        echo "{$storeArray} <br>";
    }
    //$str_dc=implode(",",$storeArray);
    //echo $str_dc;
}
```

Comment: It means you are trying to echo an array. `var_dump($storeArray)` and check the value of it!!

Comment: Your this ` $storeArray[] =  $dcode1; ` statement says you are storing `$dcode1` value in array and you are printing `$storeArray` variable. As it is array it will display **`ArrayArrayArray`** only. Use `print_r($storeArray)`

Comment: Hi @Saty, i tried to put var_dump($storeArray); And I'm getting this line:

array(1) { [0]=> NULL } array(2) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL } array(3) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }

Comment: Check my answer below because you are trying to read data before retrieve it from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assign the value of `$row_dc['Datecode'];` before fetch data from database. You need to do `fetch data inside while loop` and echo it

```
$res_dc = mysql_query($sql_dc);
if (!$res_dc) {
    echo "No data fetched!";
} else {
    while ($row_dc = mysql_fetch_array($res_dc, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row_dc['Datecode'];
    }  
 }
```

> Note:- mysql is deprecated instead use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0):

```
   else {
        while ($row_dc = mysql_fetch_array($res_dc, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $storeArray[] =  $dcode1; 
        echo "{$storeArray} <br>";
        }
```

instead try

```
   else {
        while ($row_dc = mysql_fetch_array($res_dc, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $storeArray[] =  $dcode1; 
        echo "{$storeArray[0]} <br>";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
else {
  while ($row_dc = mysql_fetch_array($res_dc, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $child =  $row_dc['Child']; 
  $Datecode =  $row_dc['Datecode']; 
  echo "$child <br> $Datecode";
}
```

if you are getting more that 1 row, use `for()` loop

```
else {
  while ($row_dc = mysql_fetch_array($res_dc, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $count = count($row_dc);
  for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++){
      $child =  $row_dc[$i]['Child']; 
      $Datecode =  $row_dc[$i]['Datecode']; 
      echo "$child <br> $Datecode";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

-first **array** don't print value using **echo**

-use print_r($array) to print  key value pair(print a array)

your solution is

```
 $i = 0;
 while ($row_dc = mysql_fetch_array($res_dc, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
          $storeArray[$i] =  $dcode1; 
          echo $storeArray[$i].'<br>';
          $i++;
  }
```

> **NOTE::-- Use single Quote instead of double Quote and mysql is deprecated instead use mysqli or PDO**